# Why aren't my watched tags yellow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, bookmarks

The questions tagged with my watched tags used to be yellow, and I found that super useful. Why are they not yellow now? Is this a problem on my end, or a change of the site?

Comment: Can't reproduce, still yellow for me. Probably best to post a bug report with screenshots and your browser version on [meta.SE] if this issue persists for you.

Comment: Related (?) post on mother meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321/263383, in particular https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken#comment1220961_366345 where another user reports this feature is still broken for them

Comment: FWIW, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ok it works now: is was a StackExchange-wide problem.